# Pass each value into array

Tags: c++, arrays

I currently stuck on storing value to an array.

Below is my progress.I would like to store each random generated number into an array.

I just created a new function prototype where supposedly,it shall read each of the generated number and store in its array.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

//Function prototype
void random(int val);
void store(int val1);


int main()
{
    int nvalue;
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to generate?\n";
    cin >> nvalue;//get input from user
    random(nvalue);//pass user input into random() function

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void random(int val)
{
    int num;//represent random integer output
    for (int i = 1; i < val; i++)//loop that will continue to generate integers based on n value from user
    {
        num = rand() % val + 1;//randomly generate number
        cout << "Num [" << i << "]" << "is " << num<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the array in your program?

Comment: Then create a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and pass it (by reference) to the function, and add the numbers to the vector.

Comment: Also note that you are not generating `nvalue` number of random numbers, but `nvalue - 1`.

Comment: As Joachim said: `void random(int val, std::vector<int>& array);`

Comment: Instead of passing an array to the function as argument, you can return a vector as well.

Comment: why `vector` since there is exactly `n` numbers?

Comment: @atlavis you mean `nvalue` ? Look where it comes from.

Comment: @WhozCraig it comes from user input. The size doesn't change later, so why `vector` instead of simple `new`?

Comment: @atlavis why manage the memory yourself? [RAII is what's for dinner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Comment: @WhozCraig It's just my opinion (an not only), that using `vector` for data container which won't be resized it's an overkill.

Comment: @atlavis You're definitely in the minority with that opinion on this site. [This description describing why](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf) is one of the most popular referrals from SO for a reason.

Comment: hmm...i have never exposed to vector before.

Answer (score 3):

here is example of implementation of what you need:

```
void random_store(int val, vector<int> &aVec);
int main()
{
   int nvalue;
   cout << "How many numbers would you like to generate?\n";
   cin >> nvalue;//get input from user

   vector<int> int_vector;
   random_store(nvalue, int_vector);//pass user input into random() function

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
void random_store(int val, vector<int> &aVec)
{
   int num;//represent random integer output
   for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)
   {
      aVec.push_back(rand() % val + 1);
      cout << "Num [" << i << "]" << "is " << aVec[i] <<endl;
   }
}
```